# How to evaluate residue of $\cot z/z^4$ at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to evaluate residue of $\cot z/z^4$ at $z=0$?
As we know :
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+f''(0)x^2/2+...$$
but $\cot(0)\to\infty$ or is undefined? I know that:
$$\tan x=x+x^3/3+2x^5/15+...$$

Comment: answer is -1/45

Comment: *Hint* Since $\cot z=\cos z/\sin z$, and since $\sin z$ has a simple zero at $0$, we know $z^{-4}\cot z$ has a pole of order $5$ at $0$. There's a formula to evaluate residues at poles. What you want is a Laurent series, not a Taylor series, and to look at the coefficient of $z^{-1}$.

Comment: Another approach is to use Bernoulli numbers, but of course this is begging the question, in some sense. Recall (?) that $$\cot z=\frac 1 z+\sum_{\nu\geqslant 0}(-1)^{\nu}\frac{2^{2\nu} B_{2\nu}}{(2\nu)!}z^{2\nu-1}$$ You can derive this from the more familiar $\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum_{\nu\geqslant 0}B_\nu\frac{z^{\nu}}{\nu!}$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff i know none of B-numbers neither i am familiar with both the formulae you provided; sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$\frac{\cos z}{z^4\sin z}$$

$$\newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\r}[1]{\frac{1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\array}[2]{\begin{array}{#1}#2\end{array}}
\newcommand{\b}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\s}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\d}[0]{\ldots}
\newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
\array{r|lll}{
&&\r{z^5}&-\b{\r{3!}-\r{2!}}\r{z^3}&+\s{\b{\r{4!}-\r{5!}}+\r{3!}\b{\r{3!}-\r{2!}}}\r{z}&+\d\\\hline
z^5-\f{z^7}{3!}+\f{z^9}{5!}+\d&&1&-\f{z^2}{2!}&+\f{z^4}{4!}&+\d\\
&&1&-\f{z^2}{3!}&+\f{z^4}{5!}&+\d\\\hline
&&&\b{\r{3!}-\r{2!}}z^2&+\b{\r{4!}-\r{5!}}z^4&+\d\\
&&&\b{\r{3!}-\r{2!}}z^2&+\r{3!}\b{\r{3!}-\r{2!}}z^4&+\d\\\hline
&&&&\s{\b{\r{4!}-\r{5!}}+\r{3!}\b{\r{3!}-\r{2!}}}z^4&+\d\\
&&&&\s{\b{\r{4!}-\r{5!}}+\r{3!}\b{\r{3!}-\r{2!}}}z^4&+\d\\\hline
&&&&&+\d
}\\
\begin{align}
R&=\r{4!}\b{1-\r{5}}+\r{3!}\s{\r{2!}\b{\r{3}-1}}\\
&=\r{24}\b{\f45}+\r{12}\b{\f{-2}3}\\
&=\r{6}\b{\r{5}-\r{3}}\\
&=\f{-2}{6\times15}\\
&=-\r{45}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I tried but can't make up the long-division in latex, the bottom portion i can easily write, i need help, anyways will try my best to make it readablle.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff done

Comment: You really need to find a better way to code this. Doesn't `\frac` work for you? You don't need to use the long division symbol.

Answer (score 5):

The function has a pole of order $5$ at zero, so it isn't defined there.

Following @PedroTamaroff's hint and using that $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}{z} = 1$ :
$$
\frac{\cot z}{z^4} = \frac{\cos z}{z^4\sin z}= \frac{z\cos z}{\sin z}\frac{1}{z^5}
$$
Observe that the first fraction is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $0$. Use Cauchy's theorem to finish.

Comment: How would Cauchy's theorem help to find the residue of $f(z)=\frac{\cot(z)}{z^4}$?

Answer (score 4):

Well,

\begin{align}\cot z = \frac{\cos z}{\sin z} &= \frac{1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} + O(z^6)}{z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} + O(z^7)}\\
& = \frac{1}{z}\cdot \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} + O(z^6)\right)\cdot \left(1 + \frac{z^2}{3!} - \frac{z^4}{5!} +\frac{z^4}{3!3!}+ O(z^6)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{z}\cdot \left(1 + \left(-\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!}\right)z^2 + \left(-\frac{1}{2!3!} + \frac{1}{4!} - \frac{1}{5!} + \frac{1}{3!3!}\right)z^4 + O(z^6)\right).\end{align}

Therefore, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the Laurent expansion of $\frac{\cot(z)}{z^4}$ is

$$-\frac{1}{2!3!} + \frac{1}{4!} - \frac{1}{5!} + \frac{1}{3!3!} = -\frac{1}{45}.$$

Hence, $$\text{Res}_{z = 0}\frac{\cot(z)}{z^4} = -\frac{1}{45}.$$

Comment: How is the coefficient of $1/z = -1/45$?

Comment: @Amad27 what do you mean?

Comment: I meant how do you derive that the coefficient of the $1/z$ term is $-1/45$? As you say above in the answer?

Comment: Look at the last line (line 3) for the expansion of $\cot z$. If you divide through by $z^4$, you find that $$\frac{\cot z}{z^4} = \cdots + \left(-\frac{1}{2!3!} + \frac{1}{4!} - \frac{1}{5!} + \frac{1}{3!3!}\right)\frac{1}{z} + O(z).$$ So the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ is $$-\frac{1}{2!3!} + \frac{1}{4!} - \frac{1}{5!} + \frac{1}{3!3!} = -\frac{1}{45}.$$

Comment: Fantastic, this deserves much more than $(+1)$

Comment: Wow, thank you @Amad27!

Comment: @kobe How did you arrive at your second equality from the first one? I'm talking about the second factor, which seems to refer to the denominator.

Comment: @MusséRedi using $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$.

Comment: @kobe What is $x$ is in this case?

Comment: @MusséRedi $x = \frac{z^2}{3!} - \frac{z^4}{5!} + O(z^6)$.

Comment: @kobe I guess that's a valid approach since $|z|<1$.

Comment: at the third equality, the coefficient of $z^2$ should be $(-\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!})$,shouldn’t it?

Comment: @glimpser yes, I had evaluated $3! = 6$, but accidentally left the factorial symbol next to $6$. Thanks for the comment.