# Laurent Series for $\cot(\pi z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent Series for $f(z) = \cot(\pi z)$ at $z= 0$.

I just need hints; I am not sure how to do this at all. I am very new to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to evaluate residue of $\cot z/z^4$ at $z=0$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080401/how-to-evaluate-residue-of-cot-z-z4-at-z-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summon the Maclaurin series (which is the Taylor series centered at $z=0$) of both $\cos(\pi z)$ and $\sin(\pi z)$, to obtain $$\cot(\pi z) = \frac{\cos(\pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)}=\frac{1-\frac 1{2!}(\pi z)^2+\frac 1{4!}(\pi z)^4-\frac 1{6!}(\pi z)^6+\cdots}{\pi z-\frac 1{3!}(\pi z)^3+\frac 1{5!}(\pi z)^5-\frac 1{7!}(\pi z)^7+\cdots}.$$

Can you do long division of the following?
$$\pi z-\frac 1{3!}(\pi z)^3+\frac 1{5!}(\pi z)^5-\frac 1{7!}(\pi z)^7+\cdots\overline{\left){1-\frac 1{2!}(\pi z)^2+\frac 1{4!}(\pi z)^4-\frac 1{6!}(\pi z)^6+\cdots} \right. }$$
Your quotient will be the first few terms of your Laurent series of $\cot(\pi z)$ centered at $z=0$.

Comment: how to do this division?

Comment: Here is a hint to get you started: $$\qquad \qquad \, \frac 1{\pi z} - \cdots \\ \pi z-\frac 1{3!}(\pi z)^3+\frac 1{5!}(\pi z)^5-\frac 1{7!}(\pi z)^7+\cdots\overline{\left){1-\frac 1{2!}(\pi z)^2+\frac 1{4!}(\pi z)^4-\frac 1{6!}(\pi z)^6+\cdots} \right. \\ -1 \\ \quad \overline{0-\frac 1{2!}(\pi z)^2} \\ \qquad \qquad \vdots }$$

Comment: I dont get it.  In the fist step you subtracted $1$ right? But you should have subtracted $(\frac{1}{\pi z})(\pi z - \frac{(\pi z)^3}{3!} ....)$  All of that? But you only subtracted $1$?

Comment: Becuase $\frac 1{\pi z} \cdot (\pi z)=1$. I didn't finish everything, but yes, you should also subtract $\frac 1{\pi z}\cdot[-\frac 1{3!}(\pi z)^3] + \frac 1{\pi z}\cdot[\frac 1{5!}(\pi z)^5] - \frac 1{\pi z}\cdot[-\frac 1{7!}(\pi z)^7]$ in the same line, which I forgot to do in my last comment.

Answer (score 10):

\begin{align}
\pi \cot(\pi z)
&=\frac{d}{dz}\ln(\sin(\pi z))\\
&=\frac{d}{dz}\left[\ln\pi z\prod^\infty_{n=1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{z}-2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{z}{1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{z}-2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{z^{2k-1}}{n^{2k}}\\
&=\frac{1}{z}-2\sum^\infty_{k=1}\zeta(2k)z^{2k-1}
\end{align}